# How to converte Long-->byteArray->String-->byteArray-->Long over socket?

Tags: java, string, sockets, byte

I want to send messages over socket that contain long values. I want to send string messages. To save bytes and make messages shorter, I want to send the byte value of a 64 bit long in 8-character string. Following is my code, but I received wrong value on the other side of the socket:

This the server:

```
public class ClockSkewServer {
public static void main (String args[]){
    try {
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(3000);
        System.out.println("Server is listening!");
        Socket connection = s.accept();
        connection.setKeepAlive(true);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), true);
        while (true) {

            String message = br.readLine(); 
            System.out.println(message);
            Long receivedTime = ByteUtil.stringToLong(message);
            System.out.println(receivedTime);



        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
    }
```

And this is the client:

```
public class ClockSkewClient {
public static void main (String args[]) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, InterruptedException{
    Socket s1 = new Socket(args[0], 3000);
    s1.setKeepAlive(true);
    PrintWriter out1 = new PrintWriter(s1.getOutputStream(), true);
    long l = new Long("1490917469228");
    //System.out.println(l);
    while (true){
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        String message  = ByteUtil.longToString(l);
        System.out.println("Client message: " + message);
        System.out.println(ByteUtil.stringToLong(message));
        out1.println(message);
    }

}
}
```

And this my byte conversion class:

```
public class ByteUtil {
    private static ByteBuffer longBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
    private static ByteBuffer shortBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Short.BYTES);  
    private static ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Byte.BYTES);  

    public static byte[] longToBytes(long x) {
        longBuffer.putLong(0, x);
        return longBuffer.array();
    }

    public static long bytesToLong(byte[] bytes) {
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getLong();
    }


    public static String longToString (long x) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        return new String (longToBytes(x), "ISO-8859-1");
    }

    public static long stringToLong (String s) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        return bytesToLong(s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
    }




}
```

ByteUtil is working fine, as the client can retrieve the original long value correctly, but when I send over socket it get distorted.

I successfully get the long value in the client side as 1490917469228, but on the server side I get 1490911439916.

I know we can send bytes and avoid this problem, but for some reason I insist to send String over socket.

Thanks

Comment: `InputStreamReader` has an optional parameter for the encoding, which matters as otherwise the computer's default encoding is taken. Use `long` - not `Long`. There are several problems with that approach. For instance byte sequences that contain a line break char. Go entirely binary, with InputStream instead of Reader. Or simply switch on compression on the Reader/Writer (GZipOutputStream, headers for deflate)

Comment: `String` is not a container for binary data. You 'insist to send String over socket' for some reason such as what? Even though it conflicts with your other stated objectives?

Comment: You are right. But this is the reason. I have a very simple protocol that recieve a message and retrive the sections of the message by a delimiter such as ; or :

Answer (score 3):

> I want to send messages over socket that contain long values. I want to send string messages. To save bytes and make messages shorter, I want to send the byte value of a 64 bit long in 8-character string.

Why? Sending 64 bits as 8 chars could take *16* bytes. 128 bits. It certainly doesn't *save* any bytes whatsoever, and all these conversions just waste time and code space: especially development time, especially as your code doesn't work.

Just use `DataOutputStream.writeLong()` and `DataInputStream.readLong()`.

Comment: You are right, but the problem is I have an application that is written and uses a string-based protocol. It was. It was better to use Google protocol buffer for indtance, but I don't want to change the code that much now. I just wanted to save some overhead by that. And I even 16 bytes matters if yiu have do many long or short values.

Comment: What 16 bytes? You can't save *anything* if you're going to use `String`, unless the values are small. You will have to send the data in ASCII format, same as in your literal.

Comment: For indtance, if you send 1490917469228 as string it will be 13 characters, so 13 bytes. But it you can send it by only 8 bytes. If you have larger number you it can be more than 13 bytes.

Comment: Sure but you can never save 16 bytes. The longest `long` is 9223372036854775807, which is 19 digits, and you need eight bytes for every binary `long`. Saving: 11 bytes tops. You would need an enormous amount of data for any saving to be siginficant.

Comment: Imagine you have lots of clinets and they sumit 1m operations per second. In this case saving only one byte saves 1MB per second.